# Give struct as parameter to a function doesnt work

Tags: c++, struct, doubly-linked-list

I created a double linked list structure, and I want to use function duplaLista to connect nodes and insert values.I have actually found in someone elses question how to give struct as a parameter in function call. But it wont work for me(Incomplete type is not allowed). I also have read answers on that issue but I cant understand what am I doing wrong because I just saw it should be done that way not that I understood it completely? Can someone tell me what is wrong, and explain me why?

```
#include "DoubleList.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include"string"
using namespace std;

struct Cvor
{
    Cvor *head;
    Cvor *tail;
    char vred;

    Cvor(const char &value, Cvor *prev = NULL, Cvor *next = NULL) : vred(value),
                                                                    head(next), tail(prev)
    {}

};

void duplaLista(Cvor *cvor)
{

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    Cvor cvor;

    duplaLista(cvor);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `duplaLista(cvor);` -> `duplaLista(&cvor);`

Comment: still does not work for me(I've read that in c++ it is ok to write it cvor without &, it shoud still work). Anyway, thanks, may You explain me this struct given as parameter little bit more ?

Comment: _!I've read that in c++ it is ok to write it cvor without &"_ Only if you declare a reference parameter.

Comment: Just as comment, your problem is not related to using a struct instead of a class. in c++, structs and classes are (almost) the same thing. The only difference I know is that by default, struct members are public and class member are private. But in both case you can use `public:` `protected:` and `private:` modifiiers to alter this defaults.

Answer (score 0):

```
void duplaLista(Cvor *cvor)
```

A compiler reads the program to compile from the beginning to the end. At this point, `Cvor` is not defined. Your definition of this class appears later.

In C++, classes, templates, functions, and everything else must be defined before they are used.

You need to move the definition of the class out of the `main()` function and into the global scope, before it is used here.

Comment: I got it, thanks !!! It works now, except for the Cvor cvor; which is in main(). 
I am missing default constructor since I moved constructor outside of the main..how can I solve it ?

Comment: If you're missing the default constructor, just declare and define the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors here. First, as you did not define a default constructor for Cvor, unless you provide the minimum essential parameters to construct Cvor, the declaration in main(i.e. Cvor cvor) will fail. You need to give it some sample const char & to be able to construct it. When that's done, you need to fix the incorrect type of parameter you provide to duplaLista. When corrected, your main function should look as follows. The parameter 'A' I gave below is just a sample initial value. Replace it with whatever you think is useful.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    Cvor cvor('A');
    duplaLista(&cvor);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought no one saw my edit, so I had to ask another question. As far as I understand, cvor should be instantiation of struct Cvor, and it should contain two pointers and char as value. What should be initial value inside brackets (than i dont understand it really). second:would I have to use &cvor, if I have duplaLista(Cvor cvor){}, and function call duplaLista(cvor). What would be difference from (Cvor *cvor) and duplaLista(&cvor) ? Hope you understand my questions! Thanks